# Why this code of ordered insertion of linked list is not working in GCC CEntos?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, linked-list

Where as the same fine on Dev-C++ (TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64-bit Release), gcc version on centos is (gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)). **Please tell me if there is any error in my coding logic or it is something else**

```
`#include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int i;
    struct node *next;
};
void main()
{
struct node *head,*temp,*p;
int d;
char ch;
printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N");
scanf("%c",&ch);
fflush(stdin);
if((ch=='y')||(ch=='Y'))
{
    printf("Enter your data: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    fflush(stdin);
    head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->i=d;
    head->next=NULL;
}
p=head;
printf("Do you want to enter more data? Y/N");
scanf("%c",&ch);
fflush(stdin);
while((ch=='y')||(ch=='Y'))
{
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter your data: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    fflush(stdin);
      temp->i=d;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(p->i>=temp->i)
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while((p->next!=NULL)&&(p->next->i<temp->i))
        {
            p=p->next;
    }
        temp->next=p->next;
        p->next=temp;
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter more data? Y/N");
scanf("%c",&ch);
fflush(stdin);
p=head;
}
while(p!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d ",p->i);
    p=p->next;
}
}`
```

Comment: Ok , now explain your problem. What's wrong? Is it failing to compile? Is it failing to run? What input are you giving? Where it is breaking?

Comment: It is taking my input for the first time and after that it doesn't and program stops working after posting one more line, here it is: 
Do you want to enter data? Y/Ny
Enter your data: 5
Do you want to enter more data? Y/N5 {It automatically took 5 as input here}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't `fflush(stdin);` so remove that (fflush is only defined for output streams).

Secondly, the stdin buffer contain the newlines that the user types after entering 'Y', 'N', or a number.  You can eliminate this whitespace by changing your `scanf` calls to have a leading space before the %c or %d, such as:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
...
scanf(" %d",&d);
```

This will solve the immediate problems I see in your code.